# Software inventory / asset management software

Tags: windows, macos, inventory

I'm looking for software to generate a list of installed applications on Windows and MacOS systems, including version and licence information.

It needs to use a client/server approach (login credentials for each machine won't be available).

The server will be a Mac and clients will be both Macs and Windows PCs.

Answer (score 1):

Spiceworks, offer an Asset Management suite free of charge. You will need to set it up on a Server / Client basis.

Quote from the website

> Get your license to… track.
>   Like to keep a handle on software and volume licenses? Want to eliminate unwanted software on your network? Spiceworks lets you keep track of all your software licenses so that you can stay in compliance and audit stress-free.

https://www.spiceworks.com/free-asset-management-software/

[image]

Comment: This was one of the first results of my Googling on the subject, but the download is an .exe - not ideal for a Mac server.

Comment: I am not aware of any asset management system that will run on Mac OS. Is VM with Windows on it possible on your environment?

Comment: That's a pretty good idea actually - I don't see a reason why not. But possibly they will be awkward about that so would have to confirm. Native Mac software would be ideal if possible.

Comment: As these applications are mostly created for business environments were Microsoft & Linux have the most market share, it will be very difficult to find something native for MacOS.