# Hardware asset management and booking system

Tags: hardware, asset-management, reservation

## Requirements

We're looking for a hardware asset management and booking system to replace a spreadsheet that's growing in complexity.

### Critical features

We need:

- Single source database to track all hardware devices

  - Hardware and software versions, IP addresses, serial numbers, and custom fields
- Web-based, preferably on-premises
- Multi-user
- Preferably open-source, but commercial is okay

### Editing

Extensive **keyboard support**:

- Inline editing of all fields (no need for super-fancy forms)
- Navigation using cursor keys (similar to a spreadsheet)
- Specify cell data input formats and range limits (e.g., IP addresses)
- User-customizable views (add/remove columns, multiple views)

### Scheduling

Individual developers will reserve various hardware components many times per day, so the **booking process** needs to be quick (i.e., no fancy forms, no multi-click UI):

- Simple data entry of independent fields: name, date, start time, and end time
- Ability to book a machine "indefinitely"
- View and edit reserved time slots alongside select details of equipment being booked

Here's a screenshot of the spreadsheet:

[image: spreadsheet]

Having the ability to customize the columns would be great.

### Data

Hardware device attributes must have **dynamic fields**.

- Capture connectivity relationships between hardware devices
- Highly normalized database, preferably database-agnostic
- REST API allowing complex queries

  - list IP addresses of all hardware having a maximum width of 60 cm
  - list IP addresses of all transceivers connected to an oscilloscope
  - list all hardware devices running Debian Linux version 9 or greater
  - list all networked devices connected to the .60 subnet

### Bonus features

Great to have, but not necessary:

- Can track software licenses (for HTML EULA generation)

### Anti-features

We don't need the following features:

- Help desk (ticketing)
- DevOps support
- Confluence integration

## Candidates

Potential solutions include:

- https://c2-itsm.com - No inline editing.
- https://snipeitapp.com/product - No inline editing.

## Graveyard

Related questions with no suitable answers:

- [Free Asset management software](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/76645/free-asset-management-software)
- [Efficient IT asset management software](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/23342/efficient-it-asset-management-software)
- [Software inventory / asset management software](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/47028/software-inventory-asset-management-software)

Comment: We edit the data _a lot_. Currently, it takes about 5 seconds to reserve equipment. If that goes to 30 seconds, we'd lose 10 minutes per day in booking time, or nearly an hour a week in developer productivity. That's why inline edits are important.

Comment: Inline editing is for both the booking and the equipment information. Basically, just like a spreadsheet, but with a database back-end. There doesn't seem to be anything that's keyboard-friendly out there.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. We're looking into https://baserow.io/.